# Which context should i use in ArrayAdapter that i extend

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Android and Kotlin and I want to extend an `ArrayAdapter<Prestation>` in my `PrestationAdapter` class but I have to supply arguments but I truly don't know which `Context` should I use. I can do it in Java without passing arguments. I'm not sure to understand how `Context` work and it's probably why I do a mistake.

I have already tried with `this`, `getApplicationContext()`, `getContext()` and some other random things. Sadly "this is not defined in this context".

```
open class PrestationAdapter(act: FragmentActivity?, resource: Int, arrayList: List<Prestation>): ArrayAdapter<Prestation?>(context!, Int ){
lateinit private var activity: Activity
private val items: List<Prestation>? = arrayList
private var objBean: Prestation? = null
private var row: Int = resource
lateinit var holder: PrestationAdapter.ViewHolder
}
```

Comment: hi ! why do you need context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already context `act: FragmentActivity` in adapter parameter! just pass it to `ArrayAdapter`

```
open class PrestationAdapter(act: FragmentActivity?, resource: Int, arrayList: List<Prestation>)
: ArrayAdapter<Prestation?>(act, Int )
```

Comment: I cant pass "act" (strangely) but i can pass FragmentActivity() and it seem to work.
You showed me the good way ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> You have to set `Context` as Adapter argument.

```
open class PrestationAdapter(act: Context?, resource: Int, arrayList: List<Prestation>): ArrayAdapter<Prestation?>(context!, Int ){
    lateinit private var activity: Activity
    private val items: List<Prestation>? = arrayList
    private var objBean: Prestation? = null
    private var row: Int = resource
    lateinit var holder: PrestationAdapter.ViewHolder
```

and when you initialize adapter then you have to pass `context` as 1st argument.

Comment: that doesnt work, but i find the solution thanks to Kishore Jethava !
I had to pass FragmentActivity()